# Unable to move div back to original position after slide

Tags: jquery, slide

I have a problem with a slidetoggle. The black box after clicking slides the second div back in which is great but itself will not slide back to it's original position. How can I fix this?

I am using Jquery UI at the moment.

Here is the code:

```
#recommended-product-block{
    position: absolute;
    top:225px;
    right:0;
    z-index: 999999;
    width:100px;
}
#weather{
    width:150px;
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
}

<div id="recommended-product-block">
    <h1>Div box to initiate slide toggle</h1>
</div>

<div id="weather">
    <h1>Box that slides in and out</h1>
</div>

$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#weather').hide();

    $(function () {
        $("#recommended-product-block").click(function () {
            $(this).animate({ right: '+150' }, 400 );
            $( "#weather" ).toggle( "slide" );
        });
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you are to toggle between both `<div>` tags it is pretty simple. First div will be hidden. On click of the second div first div will slide and second one will be gone. On click of the first div second div will slide and the first one will be gone.

```
$('#weather').hide();

$(function () {
    $("#recommended-product-block").click(function () {            
        toggle();
    });

    $("#weather").click(function () {            
        toggle();
    });
});

function toggle(){
    $( "#weather" ).toggle('slide');
    $( "#recommended-product-block" ).toggle('slide');
}
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6xuL9o4/)

(Added border for clarity)

**Edit:**

To control the speed use this toggle function

```
function toggle(){
    $('#weather').toggle('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300);
    $( "#recommended-product-block" ).toggle('slide', {direction:'left'}, 300);
}
```

**Edit (based on comment)**

```
$('#weather').hide();

$(function () {
    var notClicked = true;

    $("#recommended-product-block").click(function () { 

        $( "#weather" ).toggle('slide', 400);

         if(notClicked) {
            $(this).animate({'right':150}, 400);  
          }
          else
          {
             $(this).animate({'right':0},400);
          }

          notClicked = !notClicked;        
    });

 });
```

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/a6xuL9o4/1/)

Comment: I actually want the #recommended-product-block element to not disappear. It should slide to the left as the #weather element appears sliding out. Upon clicking the #recommended-product-block the #weather should slide back in (disappearing). 

That was why I had kept the animate method to slide to the left but upon clicking it remains at the left

Comment: @Jnsn_ Updated my answer; check & mark. I think this is what you are after.